# Does "seldom...any more" mean "not...any more"

Tags: meaning

> "No," Tyrion admitted,"not me. I **seldom** even dream of dragons **anymore**.
>   There are no dragons."

I encountered this sentence in *The Game of Thrones*. 
Is "seldom...anymore" equal to "not anymore"? Therefore, this sentence means Tyrion didn't dream of dragon. 
I feel confused because according to the context of this chapter, Tyrion said he was mad about dragon and he used to imagine it.

Comment: No, it means *seldom*- not very often- rarely.  *Anymore* can be thought of as *these days* or *nowadays*, *at this point in my life*  Tyrion rarely dreams of dragons now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seldom means rarely, so it's not as strong as "never". "The sentence literally means "I used to dream about dragons, but now I rarely dream about dragons". The implication is that he did not dream about dragons in the recent past.